# How to get the business details using google business

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, web, google-maps-api-3

I want to get the business details where added in google business. For example a person searching "computer shops in newdelhi". Then i want show all the details of computer shops in new delhi where listed in google business (or map) without showing maps. How it possible in web (php or js or any programming language in web).

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest starting with the Google Places API. This is essentially a subset of the Maps API. There is no requirement that the map itself is actually rendered.

https://developers.google.com/places/

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_details

**update:**

here is a CodePen example showing a very quick and dirty bare-bones example using jQuery.

```
var placesAPIAccessKey = '<your key here>';  

var placesSearchAPIEndpoint = 'http://crossorigin.me/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json';
var placesLookupAPIEndpoint = 'http://crossorigin.me/https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json';

var placesSearchParams = {
  key: placesAPIAccessKey,
  location: '28.5219145,77.2189402', // New Dheli, India
  radius: 5000, // 5km search radius from center point
  type: 'electronics_store',
  keywords: 'computer shop store repair service laptop notebook chromebook hp acer asus apple dell'
};

function getThePlaces() {
  $.get(placesSearchAPIEndpoint,placesSearchParams,function(data){
    $.each(data.results, function(index,content) {
      $.get(placesLookupAPIEndpoint,{
        key:placesAPIAccessKey,
        placeid:content.place_id
      }, function(data) {
        $('body').append(
          '<div>'+ 
          data.result.name + '<br>' +
          ' Address: ' + data.result.formatted_address + '<br>' +
          ' Phone: ' + data.result.formatted_phone_number +
          '</div>');
      });
    });
  });
};

getThePlaces();
```

link to live CodePen: http://codepen.io/pixelchemist/pen/RGjYEQ
* note you will need to provide your own places API key for it to work *

Comment: How to get the list of computer shops in delhi.

Comment: updated my reply with a simple example, please note you need to provide your own API which you can get from google and the http://crossorigin.me/ prefix on the endpoint uris, that is needed for codepen and can be excluded if run elsewhere

Comment: I got the result. Thanks @nathaniel